# Unable to set property 'currentDay' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting

Unable to set property 'currentDay' of undefined or null reference
while i am trying to implement a date picker on the appended text box:

```
        <td>Recoupment Month

        </td>

        <td>Amount To be Recouped  


        </td>

        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AMOUNT)
        </td>

        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DATE)

      <input type="button" id="txt" value="ADD" style="",class="btn" />

    <input type="button" id="Rmv" value="REMOVE" style="",class="btn" />

        </td>
```

script-

$.fn.rowCount = function () { return $('tr', $(this).find('tbody')).length; };

$(document).on('click', '#txt', function () {

```
    var table = $(this).closest('#advschedule');
    console.log(table.find('input:text').length);
    if (table.find('input:text').length < 7) {
        var x = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr');
        //$.each(x, function (i, val) {
        //    val.remove();
        //});
        table.append('<tr><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DATE_SCHEDULED_RECOUP) </td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AMOUNT)</td>');
        $.each(x, function (i, val) {
            table.append(val);
        });
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '#Rmv', function () {

    var table = $(this).closest('#advschedule');
    var rowCount = $('#advschedule').rowCount();

    if (rowCount > 2) {

        table.find('input:text').last().closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: can you add your markup too

Comment: You likely shouldn't be adding `@Html.TextBoxFor` through JavaScript. That control needs to be rendered on the server, and by the time the JavaScript gets to it, it'll just add it as a string, because your browser doesn't know what to do with `@Html.TextBoxFor`.

Comment: I am creating the text boxes dynamically on a button click...i am able to render the date picker but day cannot be selected...